# Помогите разобраться с отправкой .gif или url c .gif библиотека telebot / python / telegram

Tags: python, telebot, gif

Помогите отправить юзеру маленький gif + текст `lg.hello7u`, после нажатия кнопки `lg.rbtn5u`.

Есть gif url, также `C:\Test\x1`, но никак не подкидывается ни с url ни с каталога.
Благодарю!

```
# main.py
import telebot, cfg, kb, lg
from telebot import types
from requests import get
import requests

bot = telebot.TeleBot(cfg.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text, url, document'])
def cbreply(message):
   if message.text == lg.rbtn5u:
        img = open(r'C:\Test\x1\1.gif', 'rb')
        bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img, None, 'Text')
        img.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, lg.hello7u, reply_markup=kb.kbsu)

# cfg.py
url = "https://...."


# lg.py
rbtn1u = "В начало"
rbtn5u = "Начать поиск"
hello7u = "Благодарю"


# kb.py
import telebot, lg, cfg
from telebot import types

trkm = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup

#endcontact kb
rkbu4 = trkm(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
rkbu4.add(lg.rbtn5u)

#End keyboard
kbsu = trkm(True, True, row_width=1)
kbsu.add(lg.rbtn1u)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Долго перебирал методы, в итоге остановился на `send_video`:

```
img = open('/opt/bot/files/GIF/file.gif', 'rb')
bot.send_video(message.chat.id, img, None, 'Text')
img.close()
```

Comment: Нифига что-то))). переделал исходный код, все равно ничего не происходит). может я не так обозначаю путь к нему)? а как с url добавить)? если не с дика?

Comment: У вас в примере слэши в пути в другую сторону. В моем примере не windows путь

Comment: Сориии) да поменял) вот такое пишет c:\Test\x1>python main.py
  File "main.py", line 93
    img = open('C:\Users\у\Desktop\1.gif', 'rb')
               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Поставьте `r` перед 'С:\....

Comment: ни фига не происходит после экранированния этого), не меняет ничего, но хоть в ошибку перестал выбрасывать)

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "не меняет ничего"?

Comment: после нажатия lg.rbtn5u, и гифку не шлет ни текст, так и остается lg.rbtn5u

Comment: Проверьте код на простейшем примере, например на обработчике команды.

Comment: Огромный Респект! Вы правы! Все ок! Благодарю! Очень сильно помогли мне! Благодарю!

Comment: Если ответ является решением вашего вопроса, пожалуйста отметьте его (галочка), это поможет другим пользователям. Так же вы можете за него проголосовать.